# OOM killing programs when used memory is at 30%

Tags: memory-usage, linux-kernel, outofmemoryerror

I am getting a bit crazy about this one: I am getting quite often processes killed by the kernel because of OOM. I see that free reports 14 GB used out of 14 GB, but when I add up the RSS of all the processes I get to ~3-4 GB. Also, when OOM gets triggered and provides the composition of the current memory space, I get that adding up all the RSS pages together I get to 1.2 million out of 3.98 million. Swap is disabled.

If not by RSS usage... what could be the reason for OOM killing my processes?

Comment: Check your logs for OOM messages, they have all the details about memory consumption at the moment when a process was killed.

Comment: `14 GB`? Look up *memory fragmentation*.

Comment: One variant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62077590/why-can-a-user-process-invoke-the-linux-oom-killer-due-to-memory-fragmentation